# Input field not editable or somehow readonly when using in directive with ion-toggle

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[Codepen with the problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmGbJ)

this is my directive template:

```
<ion-toggle class="cw-alerttimebutton" ng-model="targetobject.isEnabled"
            ng-checked="targetobject.isEnabled">
    <input type="text" ng-model="targetobject.time" value="{{targetobject.time}}"> {{ text }}
</ion-toggle>
```

this is my app setup:

```
app.directive('cwAlertTimeButton', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: false, //toggle already replaces
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/cwAlertTimeButton.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.targetobject = scope.$eval(attrs.targetobject);
            scope.text = attrs.text;
        }
    };
});
```

**The questions:**

`<input type="text" ng-model="targetobject.time" value="1980-01-01T11:45:00.000Z"
                 class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">`

is write protected nor accessible in this place.
ion-toggle seems to use a class `item-toggle` that causes problems.

If I move the input outside of the containing element with class `item-toggle` it works as expected. As well as when I remove the class `item-toggle` from its parent.

How can I get it to work inside this construct?

The idea is to get an iphone like alarm. E.g. left the time, you click in it, you change it, right you have a toggle to enable disable it.

I use input type=text only to see if it works at all, but it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Could you please make a working JSFiddle/codepen/plunker?

Comment: @ShaojiangCai there you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmGbJ

Comment: The demo works well... And where is `item-toggle` in the code? Format your question clearly.

Comment: it is coming from the ion-toggle is my guess. I think one cannot use ion-toggle this way and has to resort to a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone still has this issue. This is caused by the class `item-toggle` that is generated by `ion-toggle`. It adds a style `pointer-events:none`.

To get it editable, overwrite the style for `pointer-events` of the `ion-toggle` to `pointer-events:all`

eg.  `<ion-toggle ng-model="onOff"  ng-change="onChange()" style="pointer-events:all;">`.

Of course, you could put this in a style sheet if you prefer. :-)